# Parse.com import data option missing in the parse dashboard

Tags: parse-platform

I am using parse.com. I know that the import data option is missing in the parse's new dashboard. But today I tried the parse's old dashboards, still I couldn't find the import data option. 
Has it been removed?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: both old and new are missing yesterday, and so do prod apps or dev apps.

Comment: Did you solve this somehow?

Comment: My scenario was, I had a development app, so I was trying to import the data from production app to development app, so in the end I downloaded the json from production app and wrote a script to read the prod json and insert in the development app.

Answer (score 1):

they removed the import from the UI, been searching for it as well :(
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/307